# derivative of equation for horizontal parabolas

Tags: derivatives, conic-sections

the equation for vertical parabolas makes sense as the tangent at the vertex of vertical parabolas has a slope of zero,
so derivative of $y=ax^2+bx+c$ which is $2ax+b$ should be 0 when we want to find out the x co-ordinate of the vertex.

but since the slope of y-axis is undefined, so derivative of $x=ay^2+by+c$ which is $2ay+b$
should be equal to undefined if we have to find out the y co-ordinate which seems weird

and further we use $y=-b/2a$ while actually finding out the y co-ordinate for the vertex.
why and how  is $y=-b/2a$ in this case?

Comment: Note that going from $x=ay^2+by+c$ to get $2ay+b$ is *taking the derivative of $x$ with respect to $y$*; that is, finding $dx/dy$. This doesn't correspond to "slope" (aka, "rise-over-run") but rather "reciprocal-of-slope" ("run-over-rise"). You've swapped horizontal and vertical components. Thus, in *that* context, the associated value for *vertical* lines is $0$, and for *horizontal* lines is "undefined"; so, you'd set $dx/dy=2ay+b=0$ (not "undefined") to find the $y$-coordinate of the vertex.

Comment: Instead of $dy/dx$ one can use $dx/dy$.

Comment: @Blue hey, could you please explain in simple terms? i'd really appericiate it. im just a sophmore in hs. so idk much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x = ay^2 + by + c$ (assuming $a\neq 0$ so that this really is a nondegenerate parabola), then you can find an expression for the slope using implicit differentiation:

$$x = ay^2 + by + c$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\Bigg(x\Bigg) = \frac{d}{dx}\Bigg(ay^2 + by + c\Bigg)$$
$$1 = 2ay\frac{dy}{dx} + b\frac{dy}{dx} + 0$$
$$1 = (2ay + b)\frac{dy}{dx}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{2ay + b}$$
The vertex would be where the tangent is vertical, so that this expression for slope is undefined, i.e., where
$$2ay + b = 0$$
$$y = -\frac{b}{2a}$$
which is well-defined since we assume $a\neq 0$.